# Error: \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pdfstartlink

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, captions, overleaf

I'm using overleaf to write my mnras report and I get this error when I am writing a caption for a figure.

```
./main.bbl:1:
pdfTeX error (ext4): \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting le
vel than \pdfstartlink.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{1}
```

My caption is this:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{SED}
\caption{Graph of relative flux against observed wavelength for a 
redshift 7 galaxy depicting the 4 wavelength breaks discussed in section 
1.3. The blue and green shaded areas at the bottom are bands used in the
Hubble Space Telescope, and the red areas are}
\end{figure}
```

but as soon as I add the next word in the caption, I get the above error. Can anyone help me please!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean that the error is occurring while you're typing in the next word? If that's the case, then perhaps switch off overleaf's automatic document build that kicks in every time you edit the document. Then remove the `.bbl` file, edit the caption and retry building the PDF.